# Typescript push object into an array, lose method definitions

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, class

Strange issue appears when i push a class instance into an array, seems like only the object attributes get pushed as I can no longer call a method defined in that object from the array. So I have the following code (i shortened it up a bit so it's as easy to read as possible).

```
class BaseSet implements ISet {
    public testAttr: string;

    constructor(baseStr) {
        this['testAttr'] = baseStr;
    }
}

class ExtendedSet extends BaseSet implements IExtendedSet {
    public testAttrExtended: string;

    constructor(baseStr) {
        super(baseStr);
        this['testAttrExtended'] = baseStr;
    }

    public test(): string {
        return 'tetetetest';
    }
}

class BaseClass {

}

class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass {
    public sets?: ExtendedSet[];
    public set?: ExtendedSet;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this['set'] = new ExtendedSet('foo');

        this['sets'] = new Array<ExtendedSet>();
        this['sets'].push(new ExtendedSet('foo'));
    }
}

let classInstance = new ExtendedClass();
console.log(classInstance.set.test());
console.log(classInstance.sets[0].test());
console.log(classInstance.sets[0].testAttrExtended);
```

Basically what happens is I push the object into the array after which I can no longer refer to methods of that object.

Here

> classInstance.set.test()

returns tetetetest, but

> classInstance.sets[0].test()

throws an error

> classInstance.sets[0].test is not a function

And then calling the testAttrExtended attribute returns foo just fine.

Is there a different approach to holding multiple instances of an object into an array?

Comment: Are you able to create a StackBlitz reproduction of the issue?

Comment: @user184994 [I did](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gcjus9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) and there's no issue. OP, consider putting your whole code.

Comment: probably not the issue, but why are you using `this['sets']`, and not just `this.sets = []`?

Comment: Did you try the basic thing which is console.log everything, to be sure the data is constructed and processed the way you want

Comment: Ok, I was able to find the problem, quite stupid actually, but it was able to drive me crazy. https://angular-va5asx.stackblitz.io  check the constructor in ExtendedMatch and tell me if you spot it too.